# R not detecting \x pattern in string

Tags: r, stringr

does someone know how it is possible de detect and replace "\x" in `R`?

```r
library(stringr)
x <- "gesh\xfc"
str_detect(x, "\\x")
# Error in stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, negate = negate, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : 
# Unrecognized backslash escape sequence in pattern. (U_REGEX_BAD_ESCAPE_SEQUENCE)

nchar(x)
# Error in nchar(x) : invalid multibyte string, element 1

iconv(x, "latin1", "utf-8")
# [1] "geshü"
Encoding(x)
# [1] "unknown"
```

Session Info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

...

locale:
[1] fr_CH.UTF-8/fr_CH.UTF-8/fr_CH.UTF-8/C/fr_CH.UTF-8/fr_CH.UTF-8
```

Context: I read a .csv file with `data.table::fread()` but this file has colnames in German with letters such as ä,ö,ü,etc. Once read in R, those letters transform into something starting with `"\x"`. This is simple unusable in R afterwards.

Comment: It is a hexcode `charToRaw("\xfc")#
[1] fc`

Comment: Thank you @akrun, but using it with my `x` string it gives a vector `# [1] 47 65 73 63 68 fc`. I don't really know how to handle a raw vector...

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: I want to remove all the `\x`, so I expect `"geshfc"`

Comment: But there is no `\x` in that string. If you print that x value you'll see "geshü". The `\x` is how you escape non-ascii values. It's not actually part of that string.

Comment: @MrFlick I think it's an interesting (and vexing) question, though, about what to do if someone has erroneously entered `\x` into your text somehow and created hexcodes that aren't "really" there, and you need to remove them.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick. My string actually prints as `"gesh\xfc"` and not "geshü" as in your case. I have added my version info above if that helps...

Comment: You can search for `\xF`, but this means after the `\x` follows one single character. So you can't find `\x` at the end of a string

Comment: @IsmailMüller Actually your `sessionInfo()` would be more helpful. You might be using a different locale which doesn't have a character for that codepoint. What do you get when you run `nchar(x)` to get the number of characters?

Comment: @joran, well if you are worried about someone accidentally typing "\x" in a literal string, there's not much you can do with it because that input has to go through the R parser and will be transformed before the next line of code can see it. Of course R will have no problems reading "\x" from a text file or something. It's only when you are literally typing string values into the console that the transformation will take place.

Comment: @MrFlick, `nchar(x)` gives `# Error in nchar(x) : invalid multibyte string, element 1`

Comment: @MrFlick The only other scenario I could think of this happening besides typing it directly is possibly pulling text data in from a db directly into R. (fwiw, I'm seeing the same printing behavior as the OP, on macOS with the default en_US.UTF-8/etc locale.)

Comment: So does `Encoding(x)` return "Unknown"? That string seems to be using latin1 encoding (the Windows default) which doesn't translate to UTF-8 which is the encoding you seem to be using so it's not even a valid string. Where is this string coming from? Why are you trying to create the value this way in your code?

Comment: @joran This must be a mac/windows things. (or utf-8/latin1 encoding thing). Can you run `iconv("gesh\xfc", "latin1", "utf-8")`? I don't have a mac nearby to test it out.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, your solution `iconv(x, "latin1", "utf-8")` works in my case !!

Comment: @IsmailMüller Sounds like you are using `fread` to read a file that's uses latin1 encoding but you are on a machine that assumes utf-8. Try using `fread(file, encoding = "Latin-1")`. Then you shouldn't have the problem in the first place. It would have been nice to start with that info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to summarize what happened here. The "\x" is NOT part of the string. This is just how R escapes values that it can't otherwise print. In the case of "gesh\xfc", the first 4 characters are basic ASCII characters, but the last character is encoded is "\xfc". In the latin1 encoding (which Windows uses by default) the `fc` character is the "ü" character. So in my windows machine, I see

```
x <- "gesh\xfc"
x
# [1] "geshü"
```

And you can look at the raw bytes of that string with

```
charToRaw("gesh\xfc")
# [1] 67 65 73 68 fc
```

You can see the ASCII hex character codes for the first 4 values, and then you can see that the `\x` was actually just used to include the "fc" character code in the string. The string itself only has 5 "characters".

But if you are not using `latin1`, the "fc" character doesn't map to anything. Basically that string doesn't make any sense in the utf-8 encoding which is what the mac uses by default. You can convert to utf-8 with

```
iconv("gesh\xfc", "latin1", "utf-8")
```

But since you got this file by importing a text file, the problem was that the R didn't know the encoding of the file wasn't UTF-8 so you wound up with these weird values. You should tell `fread` that the file came from windows so it can import the strings properly from the start

```
fread(file, encoding = "Latin-1")
```

You need to know what encoding was used to make a file you are importing especially when made by someone else. It's not really possible for programs to guess correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much @MrFlick. Indeed, I ended using `fread(file, encoding = "Latin-1")` to correctly read the file ! But it was interesting to debug this error message !