# Converting "\x" to "\\x" for stri_unescape_unicode to read a string in R

Tags: r, string, hex

I have a set of names that I need to convert from their current string form into their correct accents for graphics. One example is:

`"\xf3"`

I am trying to replace this string with:

`"\\xf3"`

So that when I run

```
stri_unescape_unicode("\\xf3")
```

I recieve:

`"ó"`

I have tried:

```
gsub("\x","\\x","\xf3")
Error: '\x' used without hex digits in character string starting ""\x"
```

However, `gsub` gets caught up in the hex digits and errors.

Comment: I do not see the difference between the two strings.

Comment: Im sorry the first string is supposed to have one backslash \ and the second should have two \\

Comment: `\x` is not a literal backslash-X in the string. https://blog.r-project.org/2022/06/27/why-to-avoid-%5Cx-in-regular-expressions/ and https://stackoverflow.com/q/56584260/3358272 might be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you do note need to replace anything, as there is no `\` in the string `\xf3`. You can use `cat('\xf3')` and you will note that this is a multibyte string. You just need to change the encoding structure:

In base R use:

```
iconv("\xf3", "latin1")
[1] "ó"
```

If you insist on using `stringi` then:

```
stringi::stri_unescape_unicode(encodeString("\xf3"))
[1] "ó"
```

To only Just changing `"\xf3"` to `"\\xf3"` you can do:

```
`Encoding<-`("\xf3", "bytes") # ie multibyte
[1] "\\xf3"

encodeString("\xf3")
[1] "\\xf3"
```